# How to wrap text around images or abstract shapes in DirectWrite with Direct2D?

Tags: winapi, direct2d, directwrite

I couldn't find an example of a block of text not rendered to a rectangular area.

Ideally, it would be nice if `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget.DrawText()` would let me provide a polygon `Geometry` instead of a rectangle.

I've tried adding a Direct2D Layer with `contentBounds`, thinking it might skip rendering text within those layers. It didn't work as expected, it just blocked render to the area still emulating text underneath.

I've also tried applying a rectangular area to `hwnd` window itself. It too blocked render but didn't shift text.

Answer (score 2):

`IDWriteTextLayout` only supports rectangular layouts, but DirectWrite supports any shape you can think of by using the lower level functions (text analysis, glyph measurement, glyph shaping). It's no easy task to write your own text layout from scratch, but I wrote a Windows 7 SDK sample containing a "FlowLayout" that demonstrates a circle and a few other simple shapes. It doesn't take arbitrary geometry, but you may be able to adapt it to your needs (see FlowLayoutSource::GetNextRect for computing the width of each line).

https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/DirectWrite/CustomLayout[image]

Answer (score 0):

DirectWrite only supports rectangular layouts, so you can't get anything more complicated automatically. You'll have to implement layout functionality yourself if you want it to work differently. Clipping arguments, like you already observed, have nothing to do with text layout.

Comment: Do you suggest I create a separate window for each line of text?

Comment: No, windows don't have much to do with that. You'll need to access lower level of shaped glyphs (see GetGlyphs), and arrange them yourself into lines, with any constraints that are suitable for you. It's complicated, so you might look at using some layout library that supports rendering with DirectWrite.